# Need to use updated Requested Date on Prepare Invoice process

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization to the Sales Orders screen, where I use a RowPersisting event to update the Requested Date to the current date upon saving.  The problem is, if the save is not executed, but the Actions.PrepareInvoice is initiated, the new Requested Date (hopefully set by the RowPersisting event) is not used.  I've tried to override the base method as follows (to save the Sales Order record with the new Requested Date before the Prepare Invoice process is run):

```
    public delegate IEnumerable PrepareInvoiceDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable PrepareInvoice(PXAdapter adapter, PrepareInvoiceDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        Base.Actions.PressSave();
        return baseMethod(adapter);
    }
```

But I receive the following error - "Error:  The previous operation has not been complete yet."

How can I ensure that a modified Requested Date is used for the Prepare Invoice process if the Sales Order record is not yet saved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution seems to be to recreate the Action method in a graph extension and add the following code:

```
        if (!adapter.MassProcess)
        {
            //****Code added to update the Requested Date to today's date...
            var soorder = (SOOrder)Base.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)].Current;
            soorder.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
            Base.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)].Update(soorder);
            //****End of code added...

            try
            {
                Base.RecalculateAvalaraTaxesSync = true;
                Base.Save.Press();
            }
            finally
            {
                Base.RecalculateAvalaraTaxesSync = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PrepareInvoice` method in case if the call is not from Processing Page(`adapter.MassProcess==false`) is calling `this.Save.Press()` anyway.
Below is the code from `PrepareInvoice` action. Before creation of the Invoice there is being called `this.Save.Press()` so any your update will be saved and used for creation of the invoice.

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Prepare Invoice", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = false), PXButton]
public virtual IEnumerable PrepareInvoice(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    List<SOOrder> list = adapter.Get<SOOrder>().ToList<SOOrder>();
    foreach (SOOrder current in list)
    {
        if (this.Document.Cache.GetStatus(current) != PXEntryStatus.Inserted)
        {
            this.Document.Cache.SetStatus(current, PXEntryStatus.Updated);
        }
    }
    if (!adapter.MassProcess)
    {
        try
        {
            this.RecalculateAvalaraTaxesSync = true;
            this.Save.Press();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.RecalculateAvalaraTaxesSync = false;
        }
    }
    PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate
    {
        DocumentList<ARInvoice, SOInvoice> documentList = new DocumentList<ARInvoice, SOInvoice>(PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>());
        SOOrderEntry.InvoiceOrder(adapter.Arguments, list, documentList, adapter.MassProcess);
        if (!adapter.MassProcess && documentList.Count > 0)
        {
            using (new PXTimeStampScope(null))
            {
                SOInvoiceEntry sOInvoiceEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOInvoiceEntry>();
                sOInvoiceEntry.Document.Current = sOInvoiceEntry.Document.Search<ARInvoice.docType, ARInvoice.refNbr>(documentList[0].DocType, documentList[0].RefNbr, new object[]
                {
                    documentList[0].DocType
                });
                throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(sOInvoiceEntry, "Invoice");
            }
        }
    });
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to explain with this.  I don't see how this relates to what I've posted.

Comment: @pmfith I have updated the answer, hope it will help you.

Comment: You wrote: "Before creation of the Invoice there is being called this.Save.Press() so any your update will be saved and used for creation of the invoice."    It's saving - but the invoice doesn't seem to be using that saved Requested Date.  It uses the one that existed before the save occurs.

Comment: @pmfith how are you checking that the old value is used? Invoice has not such field

Comment: Samvel - The Sales Order has a 'Requested Date' that gets carried over into the Date field of the Invoice.  The problem is the Requested Date isn't being saved if the save button on Sales Order is pressed and just the 'Prepare Invoice' action is initiated.  I'll post what I've figured out.

Comment: @pmfith FYI the Date of the Invoice is set to the current `Business Date`. `Requested Date` is not being carried to anywhere from Sales Order.

Comment: Not according to my testing.

Comment: @pmfith set the Requested Date to yesterday and save it. Then run Prepare Invoice Action

Comment: ok - I stand corrected - it doesn't carry over the 'Requested Date' - but it does  carry over the 'Date' field from the Sales Order.  I just verified this.

Comment: @pmfith I don't know how are you verifying that, but the code under `PrepareInvoice` is setting `ARInvoice.DocDate`(the Date field in SO Invoice's UI) to `.Accessinfo.BusinessDate.Value`. The `ARInvoice.DueDate` is carried from `SOOrder.DueDate`.